# How to create and download text/Json File with dynamic content using angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

here i want to know how can i create a text file or json file and download it with dynamic data which is going to be filled with.

below is my

**service code**

```
  validateUserData(userId) {
    var headers = new Headers();

    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/Users?userId=`+userId,{headers: headers}).map(result => {

      return result.json();

    });
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
this.service.validateUserData(userId).subscribe( res => {

       console.log(res);    
       new Angular2Txt(res, 'My Report');
     });
```

here i want to send the  **Response** to a textFile or json file which i have to create it so that user can able to download how can i do it 
[Angular package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-txt)

i tried the above package but i able to download only empty file

Comment: There is no need to send a `content-type` header for a GET request by the way

Comment: yeah i know that edited it  and any solution for the issue ?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? And also, are you using Http or HttpClient?

Comment: using angular 6 but using http only as it is upgraded from angular 4 to angular 6

Comment: You may find this easier using `HttpClient`, as it's very easy to configure it to return a `Blob`.

Comment: if possible could point me to methods to achieve it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

it does not have to use any package,try this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51806464how-to-create-and-downloa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  private setting = {
    element: {
      dynamicDownload: null as HTMLElement
    }
  }


  fakeValidateUserData() {
    return of({
      userDate1: 1,
      userData2: 2
    });
  }

  //

  
  dynamicDownloadTxt() {
    this.fakeValidateUserData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dyanmicDownloadByHtmlTag({
        fileName: 'My Report',
        text: JSON.stringify(res)
      });
    });

  }

  dynamicDownloadJson() {
    this.fakeValidateUserData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dyanmicDownloadByHtmlTag({
        fileName: 'My Report.json',
        text: JSON.stringify(res)
      });
    });
  }
  
  

  private dyanmicDownloadByHtmlTag(arg: {
    fileName: string,
    text: string
  }) {
    if (!this.setting.element.dynamicDownload) {
      this.setting.element.dynamicDownload = document.createElement('a');
    }
    const element = this.setting.element.dynamicDownload;
    const fileType = arg.fileName.indexOf('.json') > -1 ? 'text/json' : 'text/plain';
    element.setAttribute('href', `data:${fileType};charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(arg.text)}`);
    element.setAttribute('download', arg.fileName);

    var event = new MouseEvent("click");
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

```html
<a (click)="dynamicDownloadTxt()" >download Txt</a>
<a (click)="dynamicDownloadJson()" >download JSON</a>
```

Comment: This type of approach i previously followed the issue here is i am creating button in anchor tag   < a  (click)="dataDownload(id)"/>  after clicking on the anchor tag the service has to be called and that data has to be downloaded

Comment: I updated it; you can call `dynamicDownload` after service got data.

Comment: i mean u have created anchor tag in the element right and u have used button element in the template  and in my application i used <a> tag as button instead of button so this can be applicable for that also so could y updated button tag with anchor button

Comment: I change buttons to anchors, But I don't think it has anything to do with the HtmlElement you want to use. You just call the **dynamicDownloadJson** method in my example after calling the **ValidateUserDate** method

Comment: When the JSON is quite large, I am getting a network error in the download with Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, there is a library we can use to handle saving the file. I've just tested it with [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) which seems to work, so that seems a good place to start.

Secondly, configure your HTTP request to return a Blob. Using `HttpClient`, we can simply do:

```
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
```

Finally, in the subscribe, save the blob. Using the `npm` package I mentioned earlier, this would be done like so:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';

// ...

    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        saveAs(res, "myfile.json")
      })
```

The second option is the filename.

**[Here is StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhxlud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Just uncomment the `saveAs` line if you want to see it download the file.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
let res = "Text to save in a text file";
const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/csv' });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```

Comment: Incase json, it opens a new tab. Any idea how to download json?

Comment: @HardikPatel I don't know. For me, in Chrome, it opens a new tab very briefly, then the tab disappears, and file is downloaded automatically. Could it depend on your browser settings?