# Server side log files for angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am relatively new to angular 5 and typescript. I want to create log files in angular 5.Is there any third party dependencies available ? Can it be possible by using angular 5?

Answer (score 2):

In front end library, you can use console.log, console.error...

But if you want create a file log, you need do it in back end... 
Node.js, PHP, Java....

You can send the data log from the angular to you service in back end.

Comment: Thanx tiago.dont want to show errors on console.log . want to create log files in typescript only,even don't want to use back end also.

Comment: you want create log file to be downloaded ?

Comment: Yes...if its possible

Comment: Hey @Vsal i hope that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806464/how-to-create-and-download-text-json-file-with-dynamic-content-using-angular-2) help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my Angular application, I want to keep track of some activities of the user and also maintain logs of debug / error statements in Angular. For this I want to implement logs. My Business logic is written in Java which is a REST API so don't want to use that for logging debug / error statements of another layer - Angular. I can across Apache's Log4JS but can not seem to integrate it in my Angular 5 app, nor very sure if this is the right thing. My Angular app is deployed on a AWS EC2 node and that's why I want to keep track of logs if something breaks.