# Angular - How do I dynamically download a Json File

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to make a download button that download a specific part of a Json file which is displayed in a page.
I have been using lots of methods, and this one here seemed very good : [How to create and download text/Json File with dynamic content using angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806464/how-to-create-and-download-text-json-file-with-dynamic-content-using-angular-2)
But actually, it only download a part of my json file, never the others depending on the route. Let me explain.
Here is the TS I made using the solution I saw :

```
    propertyKey: Property;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router,
    ) { }
ngOnInit() {

    this.propertyKey = this.route.snapshot.data['propertyKey'];
}
JsonData() {
    return of({
      rule: this.propertyKey.rule,
      cdfRule: this.propertyKey.cdfRule,
      compiledRule: this.orgaCompiledRule,
      snippet: this.propertyKey.snippets,
      cdfSnippet: this.propertyKey.cdfSnippets,
      all: this.propertyKey

    });
  }

  private setting = {
    element: {
      dynamicDownload: null as HTMLElement
    }
  }

  dynamicDownloadTxt() {
    this.JsonData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dyanmicDownloadByHtmlTag({
        fileName: 'My Report',
        text: JSON.stringify(res)
      });
    });

  }

  private dyanmicDownloadByHtmlTag(arg: {
    fileName: string,
    text: string
  }) {
    if (!this.setting.element.dynamicDownload) {
      this.setting.element.dynamicDownload = document.createElement('a');
    }
    const element = this.setting.element.dynamicDownload;
    const fileType = arg.fileName.indexOf('.json') > -1 ? 'text/json' : 'text/plain';
    element.setAttribute('href', `data:${fileType};charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(arg.text)}`);
    element.setAttribute('download', arg.fileName);

    var event = new MouseEvent("click");
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

}
```

and in the the template :

```
<div *ngIf="router.isActive('orga-data-model/property/jsondisplay/rule', false)" [appJsonFormatter]="propertyKey.rule">
    <div style="text-align-last: right; margin-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <a style="font-size: 1.5em;" (click)="dynamicDownloadTxt()">Download Json</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div *ngIf="router.isActive('orga-data-model/property/jsondisplay/cdfruleorga', false)" [appJsonFormatter]="propertyKey.cdfRule">
    <div style="text-align-last: right; margin-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <a style="font-size: 1.5em;" (click)="dynamicDownloadTxt()">Download Json</a>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="propertyKey.cdfRule === null || !propertyKey.cdfRule">No Data</div>
</div>
```

So, in My template, displaying the json is not a problem. And It works just fine. When when I want to download the part of that json displayed in a specific url, well, it doesnt work, it always download the same Json.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: can you share a stackblitz of this problem?

Comment: this will be difficult, there is plenty of differents services in order the json to work and be displayed.
But the problem here is how making the jsonData function to be dynamic and only refers to the data on the route and not the declared one within the function. Otherwise, i guess i would always have the same data coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the line:

```
this.propertyKey = this.route.snapshot.data['propertyKey'];
```

It's only executed once (on init), which means that when you navigate to another page (rendered by the same Component) your `propertyKey`-references isn't updated.

Instead, try this:

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.propertyKey = data['propertyKey'];
});
```