# Is there a way to create a textfile from a button press on angular?

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm building a token generator and I need a way to copy the generated token into a new textfile with "{user's name}-token" as the name of the file. I can't find anything about opening a new file from a button press, how can I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806464/how-to-create-and-download-text-json-file-with-dynamic-content-using-angular-2/51806590